# Are there any softwares which can solve equations from number theory?

Tags: number-theory, systems-of-equations, math-software

Are there any softwares which can solve equations from number theory?
For example, solve equations $x+y+z=100$, $x\equiv 2~{(\rm mod~5)}$, $y\equiv 3~{(\rm mod~7)}$, $2x+3y=50$, where $x,y,z$ are positive integers. Is there a software that can do this work?

Comment: I pretty sure all CAS can solve this, do you have criteria in mind, like free software for instance ? You can also plug it to online WA ( https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2By%2Bz%3D100%2C+x+mod+5%3D2%2C+y+mod+7%3D3%2C+2x%2B3y%3D50+integer+solve )

Comment: Thank you very much！